# enlarge images with hover on slider bootstrap3 Slide Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I view [this code sample](https://codepen.io/RyGanley/pen/JKwaC) to enlarge an image.

I try used it in [bootstrap3 Slide Carousel](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36967/).

I try add 'enlarge' class bootstrap3 slide carousel items.:

```
<div class="item active">
   <div class="item-item col-md-3 col-sm-4">
     <a href="#">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&text=1" class="img-responsive enlarge">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.enlarge {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.enlarge:hover {
    width: 120%;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

you can see change [here in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36970/).

but it can not enlarge.how can I do it?

Comment: It does enlarge the image in the fiddle! what is the issue?

Comment: @NarenMurali I edit my post. for smaller width it works. but for width:100% not works.

Comment: It enlarges for `width:100%` can you check this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8wz1f7p8/)

Comment: @thanks for answer. 100% is natural size. I want enlarge it for example 120%

Comment: this won't work by scaling the items that are sliding

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, if you want to increase the width of the image to suppose `120%`, the increase will work perfectly fine. But `bootstrap.min.css` has the following style properties for `img` element.

**CSS:**

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Thus you are not able to scale above `100%` if you add the class.

```
.carousel .img-responsive{
  max-width:none;
}
```

It will override the CSS in bootstrap, if you any reason you are not able to view the changes you can add `!important`, which will override on priority.

```
.carousel .img-responsive{
  max-width:none !important;
}
```

This will apply to all the images under the carousels.

If you want to specify only for one carousel, you can specify the ID of the carousel, like

```
#myCarousel .img-responsive{
  max-width:none;
}
```

Here is a working DEMO.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>